# C Error when sharing memory between child process with active wait

Tags: c, shared-memory

I'm trying to do a program with shared memory between a child process and a father process. The program also use forks.

The objetive of the exercise is:
-Father send to the child (with shared memory) 3 times a vector with active wait

-Child receive the vec, print it and change the synchronize variable

```
  Struct:
    typedef struct{
    int change[NUM_TOTAL];
    int synchronize;
    }Exchange;
```

---

```
Exchange *vec;

int fd = shm_open("/shmtest8",O_CREAT| O_RDWR,S_IRUSR|S_IWUSR); 
//Check shm_open error
ftruncate(fd, 100);
vec = (Exchange*)  mmap(NULL,100,PROT_READ|PROT_WRITE, MAP_SHARED, fd ,0);      

     x = forkFunc()  //Creates a fork, and return 0 to parente and > 0 to child process
    if(x == 0){  //Parent
    int cont = 0;

    while(cont != 3){
        printf("Father\n");
        vec->synchronize = 1;  //Now go to to the child

        while(vec->synchronize!=0); //the child change the variable to 0                
        cont++;
        printf("cont %d",cont);
    }


    wait(NULL);

    munmap(vec,sizeof(vec));
    close(fd);
    shm_unlink("/shmtest8");


}else if(x > 0){   //Child

    int cont = 0;

        while(vec->synchronize!=1);   //Exit while when father change the variable to 1
        int i;

    for(i = 0; i < 10; i++){
            printf("%d\t",i);
        }

        vec->synchronize =0;    //Return to the father
}
```

Here is the exemple of an output:

```
     Father
     Child
      0 1   2   3   4   5   6   7   8   9
     cont 1
     Father
```

After the first iteration the program freezes after the "while(vec->synchronize!=0);" ... i guess the problema exist in the child process, but i dont know why...Any ideas?

Thank you

Comment: The child only flips `synchronize` to `1` once, then it toggles it back to `0` and exits.  The parent process is thus stuck on the second iteration of its main loop in a never-ending busy wait for the (terminated) child to toggle the shared variable once more.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think your child process part should have 1 more while loop

```
while(cont != 3){
     while(vec->synchronize!=1);   //Exit while when father change the variable to 1
     int i;
     for(i = 0; i < 10; i++){
          printf("%d\t",i);
     }

     ec->synchronize =0;    //Return to the father
     cont++
 }
```

Answer (score 1):

Don't know off-hand, but I can tell you that any time two threads are writing to the same variable (`vec->synchronize`), you are in for trouble.  For synchronization like this, please allow me to recommend pipes or [semaphores](http://www.csc.villanova.edu/~mdamian/threads/posixsem.html).  Use shared memory only when only one thread writes, or when you use other mechanisms (like semaphores or mutexes) to control access to the shared memory.

Comment: i know how to use the semaphores but i'm not allowed

Comment: OK, then Google how semaphores are implemented at a low level using shared variables, and write your own implementation :) .  Not kidding - that's actually what I'd do if I only had shm available.  Once you have working semaphores (or even mutexes), everything gets much easier.  See, e.g., [Peterson's Algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Peterson%27s_algorithm) for a starting point.

Answer (score 1):

If you can't use semaphores, use signals and signal handlers instead. If you can't use signals I can see two other solutions:

1. Use masks to block all signals when your code is in the critical zone (modifying the shared memory). This way you assure that the data shared memory is not corrupted.
2. Instead of doing `while(vec->synchronize!=1)` you should use an atomic function, like Test&Set. The problem with this is that it is pretty hard to implement in software.

Now, the biggest downside of these already not too very good solutions, is that they will not work in multiprocessor systems.

Comment: Nevado, you are correct to post this as an answer :) .  Welcome to the site!